# Не работает комментирование кода в PHP

Tags: php, vagrant

Запустил vagrant up  в проекте yii2, закомментированный код отображается мне во view, второй день бьюсь с этой проблемой, не могу понять в чём дело?

Код:

```
        <div class="col-md-4">
<!--            --><?//= $form->field($model, 'client_phone')->textInput(['placeholder' => 'Например 037-60-43'])->label('Телефон клиента') ?>
        <?=            $form->field($model, 'client_phone')->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(), [
            'mask' => '+7 (999) 999-99-99',
        ])->label('Телефон клиента');
        ?>
    </div>
```

Отображается вот так:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<!--            --><!--?//= $form--->field($model, 'client_phone')-&gt;textInput(['placeholder' =&gt; 'Например 037-60-43'])-&gt;label('Телефон клиента') ?&gt;
        <div class="form-group field-propertysearch-client_phone">
<label class="control-label" for="propertysearch-client_phone">Телефон клиента</label> 
...
```

[image: код]
[image: view]

Comment: Мыслей сразу несколько.
1. Каким образом обрабатываете вызов вьюхи (`return $this->render('...');`)? 
2. Настроена ли обработка коротких тегов в конфигах PHP? Ибо тег PHP `<?=` он знает, а `<?` - для него обычный, не-phpшный тег. 
Поэтому, попробуйте 1) заменить код `<!-- --><?//= $form->field($model, 'client_phone')->...` на `<!--            --><?php //= $form->field($model, 'client_phone')->...` 2) https://ixnfo.com/kak-vklyuchit-korotkie-tegi-php.html

Comment: включил короткие теги - помогло, спасибо!

Comment: Хорошо) Тогда вынесу комментарий в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тег `<?=` PHP воспринимает, как известный ему, а `<?` - для него обычный, не-phpшный тег. Поэтому можете попробовать:

1) заменить тег `<?` в коде `<!-- --><?//= $form->field($model, 'client_phone')->...` на `<?php`

2) включить обработку коротких тегов в конфигах php.

Рекомендую всё же первый вариант, т.к. в тег `<?` может быть началом XML-файла и тогда возникнет путаница для интерпретатора PHP, что может привести к ошибке при попытке обработать содержимое тега.